# Best way to check if a partial(Class) is an instance of Class

Tags: python

So here's my setup:

```py
from functools import partial

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, some_kwarg=0):
        pass

def func(class):
    # VERSION 1: I don't do anything

    # VERSION 2: I do this
    class = partial(class, some_kwarg=1)
   
    # check if class points to MyClass
    ### THIS is where I want your input stack overflow
```

So there are a few things going on here for me:

1. In VERSION 1 should I do `class == MyClass`?
2. In VERSION 2 how do I modify the answer to 1 to account for the `partial`. My naive solution is `class.func == MyClass`
3. How do I handle cases where I don't know which version it will be? My naive approach is `(class == MyClass or (isinstance(class, partial) and partial.func == MyClass))`

Comment: Don't check it via equality, always use `isinstance` or `issubclass`, i.e. `issubclass(class.func, MyClass)`.

Comment: That helps. So I then modify 3 to be: `(issubclass(class, MyClass) or (isinstance(class, partial) and issubclass(partial.func, MyClass)))`... well almost. This breaks things because if I'm using `partial`, `issubclass` gets angry at arg 1 not being a class

Comment: Then swap the operands: `isinstance(class, partial) and issubclass(partial.func, MyClass) or issubclass(class, MyClass)` should work.

Comment: @L3viathan yep. If you're convinced that's the best way to go about it, happy to accept "yes with these tweaks" as an answer. Otherwise I'll wait

Comment: You mean `from functools import partial`, I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `class` is a reserved word, so I'll use `class_` instead (per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)).

1. Use `is` instead of `==`, to check identity instead of equality (though they'll usually be the same when dealing with class objects).

   ```
   class_ is MyClass
   ```

   Or, if you need to account for subclasses, use [`issubclass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass), which includes the case where `class_ is MyClass`.

   ```
   issubclass(class_, MyClass)
   ```
2. See point 1, just replace `class_` with [`class_.func`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial.func).
3. You're on the right track. I would just try to flatten out that nested expression, maybe like this:

   ```
   departial = class_.func if isinstance(class_, partial) else class_
   departial is MyClass
   ```

Example:

```
from functools import partial

class MyClass:
    pass

for class_ in MyClass, partial(MyClass), range, partial(range):
    departial = class_.func if isinstance(class_, partial) else class_
    result = departial is MyClass
    print(result, class_)
```

Output:

```
True <class '__main__.MyClass'>
True functools.partial(<class '__main__.MyClass'>)
False <class 'range'>
False functools.partial(<class 'range'>)
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass` is callable, and returns an instance of `MyClass` when called.

`partial` just wraps `MyClass` in a callable object that, when called, calls `MyClass` with some predetermined arguments.

`partial(MyClass)()`, *by definition*, will return an instance of `MyClass`. You don't need to check.

(While it's possible to override `MyClass.__new__` to return something *other* than an instance of `MyClass`, that's not something you would need to check *because* of `partial`.)

Comment: "You don't need to check." Yes, but I want to check this before I instantiate.

Comment: There's nothing to check before you instantiate. But again, what reason do you have to think `MyClass` (or the `partial` wrapper) *won't* return an instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: The reason I need to check before I instantiate is because MyClass is a one of a family of related classes, but it's the only special one that requires different instantiation arguments. The user may provide any of this family of classes. So on instantiation I check if it happens to be the special one, and if so I provide the appropriate args/kwargs

Comment: That sounds like a larger design issue to fix, so that you have a uniform interface.

Comment: Good to know. Thank!